# How do I count the amount of times a specific word comes up in an array list

Tags: java

I have a class that takes in a txt file with artists and their genre in the format:
Abba Rock
Beethoven Classical

I am trying to write a method "public int count(String genre)" that counts the amount of times that word/genre is present. For example, for rock, it would need to count the number of rock artists and satisfy my test case:

```
public class ArtistTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {    
      Artists artists = new Artists();
      System.out.println(artists.count() + " artists in the list");
      System.out.println(artists.count("Rock") + " rock artists in the list\n");
```

My initial count method successfully counts the number of artists (I guess there would be a better way to do that)

My code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Artists {

    public static ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(readArtists("artists30.txt"));
        System.out.println(artists + "\n");
    }

    public Artists() {
    }

    public static boolean readArtists(String fileName) {
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("err " + fileName);
                return false;
            }
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                artists.add(sc.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int count() {
        int count = artists.size();
        return count;
    }

    public int count(String genre) {
    }
}
```

What I'm testing with:

```
public class ArtistTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {    
      Artists artists = new Artists();
      System.out.println(artists.count() + " artists in the list");
      System.out.println(artists.count("Rock") + " rock artists in the list\n");
        
      System.out.println("File opened successfully? " + artists.readArtists("artists30.txt"));
      System.out.println("\n" + artists.count() + " artists in the list");
      System.out.println(artists.count("Rock") + " rock artists in the list");
      System.out.println(artists.count("R&B") + " R&B artists in the list");
    
      
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you're using a single string to keep both artist and genre I think many method will break as soon as you get to "Kid Rock". I would keep artist and genre separated into two class fields and make a list of `Artist`s, not a list of `String`s. Then you can count occurrences of a genre a lot more easily.

Comment: Please show the `Artist` class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm old school.  All that new Streams stuff spins my head around.  I like to keep things simple.  My way to what you want is to do two simple things:

1. Define an Artist object that will represent the info on each artist.  This object knows how to construct itself from a line in the data file.
2. While reading in the artists, create a second by-genre index that will give you a list of artists for each genre.

The other thing I did was make things non-static, so you actually instantiate an Artists object, in case you ever wanted to have multiple lists of artists.

Here's my rendition:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Artists {

    public class Artist {

        public String name;
        public String genre;

        public Artist(String line) {
            String[] parts = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            name = parts[0];
            genre = parts[1];
        }
    }

    private List<Artist> artists = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, List<Artist>> genres = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean readArtists(String fileName) {

        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("err " + fileName);
                return false;
            }
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                // Turn the line into an Artist object
                Artist artist = new Artist(sc.nextLine());
                // Add it to the main list of artists
                artists.add(artist);
                // Add it to the per-genre index
                if (!genres.containsKey(artist.genre))
                    genres.put(artist.genre, new ArrayList<>());
                genres.get(artist.genre).add(artist);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int count() {
        return artists.size();
    }

    public int count(String genre) {
        if (genres.containsKey(genre))
            return genres.get(genre).size();
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Artists artists = new Artists();
        String filepath = "/tmp/artists30.txt";
        if (artists.readArtists(filepath)) {
            System.out.printf("Artist Count: %d\n", artists.count());
            System.out.printf("Rock Artist Count: %d\n", artists.count("Rock"));
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("Failed to read artists file '%s'\n", filepath);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
Abba Pop
Beethoven Classical
Rush Rock
Aerosmith Rock
Mozart Classical
AC/DC Rock
Yes Rock
```

Result:

```
Artist Count: 7
Rock Artist Count: 4
```

Comment: I like this more simplistic approach. Is there a way to scan the text file within the boolean readArtists method though?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  Aren't we still doing that here?  `readArtists` is just an instance method rather that a static (class) method, but still reads the file and returns a `boolean`. Do you want to be able to call `readArtists` without first creating an `Artists` object?  I thought of doing that, but I'd have no way of returning both an `Artists` object and a `boolean` result.

Comment: Specifically, this is what my programming assignment is asking: "boolean readArtists(String filename): adds to the list all of the artists stored in the
file passed as parameter. 
 The readArtists method should return true if the file is opened
successfully. Otherwise, the method should handle the exception, display an appropriate
error message containing the name of the missing file, and return false."

Comment: I edited the post to include the test class that I was given to test this, which I am not trying to alter. It's throwing a null pointer exception

Comment: the null pointer exception was pointing at "        return genres.get(genre).size();
"

Comment: Is there a test for the count of a genre that doesn't exist?  I wasn't handling that case.  I just updated the `count(genre)` method to fix that.

Comment: so I deleted the other question because I've obviously gone down the wrong path of a needlessly gratuitous rabbit hole of counter productive answers. I shouldnt have utilized this code you mentioned above and gone a different path that doesnt use multiple classes when this could have been done with one.

Answer (score 0):

Well as long as your mapping will be "artist" + "space" + "genre" you could try the following code. This creates a map with all the genres as key, and the value is the respective count for the genre.

```
class Grouper {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var grouper = new Grouper();
    grouper.groupByGenre();
}

void groupByGenre() {
    List<String> musicCollection = List.of("Kid Rock", "Hello Rock", "Beethoven Classical");
    var collection = musicCollection.stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.split(" "))
            .filter(strings -> strings.length == 2)
            .map(strings -> new MusicCollection(strings[0], strings[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MusicCollection::getGenre, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(collection);
}
}

class MusicCollection {
private final String artist;
private final String genre;

public MusicCollection(String artist, String genre) {
    this.artist = artist;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}
```

}

EDIT:
To make it simpeler, replace your count method with the following:

```
    public int count(String genre)
{
    return (int) artists.stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.split(" "))
            .filter(strings -> strings.length == 2)
            .map(strings -> strings[1])
            .filter(value -> Objects.equals(value, genre))
            .count();
}
```

Comment: You need to know about `Stream API` introduced from `Java 8` to understand above code.

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey checkout the edit, and indeed try to invest some time in learning the stream api, as it is very powerful.

Comment: add "import java.util.Objects;" at the top